# Curves in plain edges

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, geometry

I'm following a course in Blender. My assignment is to replicate a Bobcat S175:
[image]

I'm stuck at the part where I need to create the arms and back of the vehicle. This is how far I got:
[image]

For the arms I will need some sort of curves in the plains. I am wondering how to to this. To be more clear, I want to create these parts:

[image]

I hope someone has suggestions!

---

**Edit:** I tried making a mesh which looks like the back of the vehicle. I applied the sub surf modifier to this object and tried to play with the edge creases. However, I can't seem to get it better than this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those kind of shapes you can try using curves.
Start with a bézier curve, trace your object and make it a closed curve by selecting the first and last segments and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Make the curve a 2D curve and give it some extrusion.

[image]

Repeat that for the rest of the pieces.

[image]

Comment: another example of using the totally underestimated curves of Blender

Comment: I also love using Bezier Curves although I know they are a very unpopular method among Blenderheads, and for obvious reasons like topology issues. Still, for architecture and construction and mixed curve/straight geometries they are a godsend